# Push value to Array in TS

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have the following code and I want to push the values, but I got the error that number is not a type for the array.

```
someArray: Array <{ m: number, d: Date}> = [];

this.someArray.push(500,new Date(2020,1,15));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare `someArray: Array <{ m: number, d: Date}> = [];`, it means `someArray` is array of object `{ m: number, d: Date}`.

Hence you need to pass `{ m: number, d: Date}` type of object while pushing elements in array.

Change it as follows,

```js
someArray: Array <{ m: number, d: Date}> = [];

this.someArray.push({m: 500, d: new Date(2020,1,15)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or an alternative method with spread operator :

```js
const newItem = { m: 500, d: new Date(2020,1,15) };
this.someArray = [...this.someArray, newItem];
```